# loading html from scriptJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I am using VueJS, after compiling code in the production mode. I have 1 index.html and some assets. The assets I upload all to the cloud.

The problem I'm facing is the client doesn't accept the HTML file. They require only 1 line  to load all the things

Is there any package npm support for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "client doesn't accept the HTML file."? How your app will be rendered in the browser without HTML file?

Comment: The client want the AdTag instead of the full HTML file. And they give us an example: "<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>".
This script will load all the things they want.
Because the index.html is not too complicated, I could do it by pureJS, but I wonder if any lib could support for that easier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `vue-custom-element` package. This will give you an ability to define custom element which you can use as `AdTag` after build.

Check this out: [Vue Custom Element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-custom-element)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Hardik, it's a good lib to do the magic thing, but it seems like not exactly what the client want. I will google more about and if there's no better way to do it, I have to write some code to wrap it manually (file by file)